# What does VS Code's setting html.format.unformatted do?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out what the VS Code `html.format.unformatted` setting does, but I can't.

I've found [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/4066) and [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/4262) in GitHub, but it explains nothing.

Can someone please explain to me what the `html.format.unformatted` setting does and how it differs from the `html.format.contentUnformatted` setting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After much trial and error i found out this:

**TLDR:**

- `html.format.unformatted`: does not format the tag itself nor the content
- `html.format.contentUnformatted`: will format the tag but not the content

source (not very clear, imho): https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/html

---

Sample html code (not valid, i know, but irrelevant here):

```
<body>

    <style class="foo"        class="foo"        class="foo"    >
            .foo {
            background-image: 'bar.jpeg';
            background-size: cover;
            background-position-x: 50%;
            background-position-y: 50%;
            }
    </style>

    <div class="foo">
        <div>
            <div></div>
            whatever
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

With this config:

```
{
    "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-expand-multiline",
    //"html.format.contentUnformatted" : "style",
    "html.format.unformatted": "style"
}
```

When we trigger an auto format on the sample html above, the STYLE TAG IS NOT formatted and the style tag content IS NOT changed.

With this config:

```
{
    "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-expand-multiline",
    "html.format.contentUnformatted" : "style",
    //"html.format.unformatted": "style"
}
```

When we trigger an auto format on the sample html above, the STYLE TAG IS formatted (spaces, ident, etc), the style tag content IS NOT changed.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I've spent a lot of time trying to figure that one out, but I was using the "html.format.wrapAttributes": "auto" so the tags themselves weren't changing.