# How can I modify the default formatter behavior on a custom element?

Tags: visual-studio-code

We have a custom inline element `comment`. The HTML doc fragment is something like:

```
<i><comment>text</comment></i>
```

However, the default HTML formatter would take `comment` as a block element and finally, we have:

```
<i>
    <comment>text</comment>
</i>
```

Extra text would stop adding new lines but that is not what I'm looking for:

```
<i>text<comment>text</comment>text</i>
```

I checked the `HTML>Format` settings but find only "Extra Lines"/"Reserve New Lines"/...

I also checked [vscode-html-languageservice](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-html-languageservice/blob/main/docs/customData.md) but seems nothing to do with "element type" (inline/block).

Any suggestions?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/58193498/11107541, but I wonder if it will work here... they're for preventing formatting of an element and/or its contents- not the element that contains it...